# question about continuity of a function that maps a non-compact set to the plane

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f: [0, 2 \pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ be function with

$$ f(x) = ( \cos x , \sin x ) $$
Notice $f( [0, 2 \pi ) ) = S^1 $. I want to know about the continuity of the function 
$$ f^{-1} : S^1 \to [0,2 \pi ) $$

it seems to be not continuous but I am unable to find an open set $O$ in $[0, 2 \pi)$ such that $f( O)$ is not open. Maybe this function is indeed continuous? thanks in advanced.

Comment: The function is not continuous indeed. $[0,1)$ is open in $[0,2\pi)$, but the preimage is not in $S^1$.

Comment: you mean $f( [0,1) )$ is not open in $S^1$? Can you show that ?

Comment: A neighborhood of $(1,0)\in S^1$ always contains points of the form $(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ with $x<0$. Note that the preimage of $f^{-1}([0,1))$ does not contain such points.

Comment: A set is open iff all points in the set have a neighborhood contained in the set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $y_n=(\cos 2\pi-1/n,\sin 2\pi-1/n)\in S^1$.

$y_n\to (1,0)$ in $S^1$ but the preimege $2\pi-1/n\not\to$ in $[0,2\pi)$.

EDIT: alternative proof using the crucial fact in Brian's answer.

If $f^{−1}$ is continuous, then $f$ is a homeomorphism between $[0,2\pi)$ and $S^1$, but $[0,2\pi)$ and $S^1$ aren't homeomorphic (easy proofs via compactness, connectedness...).

Comment: $S^1=f([0,2\pi))$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quick way to prove $f^{-1}$ is not continuous using the fundamental group. Seeking a contradiction, suppose $f^{-1}$ is continuous so $f$ is a homeomorphism. Then $\pi_1(f):\pi_1([0,2\pi))\rightarrow\pi_1(S^1)$ is an isomorphism, a contradiction since $\pi_1([0,2\pi))\simeq 0$ and $\pi_1(S^1)\simeq\mathbb Z$.

Of course, this might be a bit beyond the scope of this particular question, but it's a nice motivation to study algebraic topology!

Comment: Nice overkill :-).